Laravel/Reactnative Firebase send error: Request contains an invalid argument
In my project where I use React-native and Laravel, I encountered an error in the notifications section. While I can receive notifications on the Android side without any issues, on the iOS side, when I try to send a notification using the same functions but changing only the fcm_token variable, I encounter this error. Is there anyone who knows the reason or can help?
Laravel side
function sendFirebaseNotification($to, $title, $body, $data = [])
{
    try {
        $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(config('firebase.credentials'));
        $messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
        $message = [
            'token' => $to,
            'notification' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $body,
            ],
            'data' => $data,
        ];

        try {
            $messaging->send($message);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Firebase send error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Firebase configuration error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

public function sendNotification()
{
    $fcm_token = "***";
    $title = "title";
    $body = "body";
    $data = [
        'key' => 'value',
    ];
    $response = $this->sendFirebaseNotification($fcm_token, $title, $body, $data);
    Log::info($response);
    if ($response) {
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Notification sent successfully']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Notification not sent'], 500);
    }
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Notification sent successfully']);
}

React-native
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import {
  checkInitialNotification,
  onBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onMessageListener,
  onNotificationOpenedApp,
  registerAppWithFCM,
} from './src/messagingHandler';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '**********',
  authDomain: '********',
  databaseURL: '**********',
  projectId: '***********',
  storageBucket: '**********',
  messagingSenderId: '*********',
  appId: '***********',
  measurementId: '**********',
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

PushNotification.createChannel({
  channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel',
  channelName: 'Default Channel',
});

PushNotification.configure({
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);

    if (notification.userInteraction) {
      navigationRef.current?.navigate(notification.data.stack.toString(), {
        screen: notification.data.screen,
        params: notification.data.params,
      });
    }
  },

  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

registerAppWithFCM();

onMessageListener(remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Foreground message received:', remoteMessage);
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId: 'fcm_fallback_notification_channel',
    title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
    message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
    data: remoteMessage.data,
  });
});

onNotificationOpenedApp();

checkInitialNotification();

onBackgroundMessageHandler();


I have tried many different things, but none of them worked. On the Laravel side, I get this error in the log.

Based on the official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message, you have to use to as key identifier for recipient device token while in your example you are using token instead.
Note: Do not publish confidential data such as FCM tokens or passwords in your questions or any public forum, you can replace them with 3 asterisk marks instead.

The $to here is just the name of the variable, it doesn't matter. If there was an issue, I don't think the notifications would be sent on the Android side either. I'm only having issues on iOS. (Additionally, the fcm_token belongs to a simulator, but I changed it anyway, thank you.)

this 'token' => $to, should changes to 'to' => $to

When I do this, I get the following error: Firebase send error: The given message is missing a target. so token is right

With the same token, I created a campaign through Firebase, and I still did not receive a notification on my iOS device. I think the issue might be in React Native.
